# Can I use "work to" as a synonym of "make an effort to"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, verbs

In my native language, we use the verb for "work" + the infinitive marker to indicate that someone is making an effort/striving/endeavouring/trying to do something. To me, it seems that all these expressions (*make an effort, strive, endeavour, try*) have a very strong sense of 'doing one's best, but with a strong possibility of not succeeding', but I need a more neutral expression. So, now I'm wondering whether it is possible to use "work" in this sense in English too; more specifically, would the following examples be idiomatic, or is there another verb that would be a better fit?

> In the following months, we will **work to** establish cooperation with X.

> They will **work to** create a more tolerant workplace.

> They promised to **work to** increase the number of sustainable options.

Comment: @Lambie YES!!!! Yes!!! That's exactly what I'm after!! Thank you!!!

Comment: @Lambie Could you put that in an answer, so I have an answer to check as the one solving my problem?

Comment: @Lambie And in many cases I could also turn the gerund into a regular NP, right? So I'd have "work towards a more tolerant workplace" and "work towards an increased number of sustainable options" – right?

Comment: Yes, right, Gerda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question:

**To me, it seems that all these expressions (make an effort, strive, endeavour, try) have a very strong sense of 'doing one's best, but with a strong possibility of not succeeding', *but I need a more neutral expression*. **

**work to do something** is fine in English.

But I think what you want is: **to work towards something**. It's followed by a gerund: **We'll work towards creating a more tolerant workplace.**

work towards something means you haven't yet reached a particular goal.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, these are all correct and idiomatic in English. In these expressions, the word "work" essentially means "to exert effort," and the *to*-infinitive expresses the purpose of that effort.